# How to compile a specific part of c++ code using gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

Can I compile a specific function or a simple statement of a c++ program using c compiler?

Comment: Can you give a use case? Since C is a subset (ish) of C++, it should work just fine using the C++ compiler anyway.

Comment: @slugonamission, that will break malloc, at least, and probably a lot of other stuff.

Comment: Sorry, that example of using `extern "C"` is terribly wrong come to think of it. I've removed it again.

Comment: A C compiler? Or gcc? And what is the specific function or statement? (And is it valid C?)

Comment: @slugonamission, I meant compiling C code with c++ would break malloc; I think the `extern "C"` part might compile fine (although it would still compile it as c++, since it only changes the linkage).

Comment: @Amritendu, also, congrats on asking a question that can legitimately be tagged both `c` and `c++`, that's suprisingly rare.

Comment: You should really describe what you are trying to get from doing this.  Most likely it's not the right approach and there's a good way to get exactly what you want in a more standard way.  And if there's not, the only way people are going to stop telling you this is if you tell us why you want to do it, anyhow

Comment: @DavidX - ah, sorry, I thought you meant the `extern "C"` would break malloc etc. I removed it anyway since it's basically only good for the declarations in the first place. How does it break malloc though? :S

Comment: @all  - Hey, I am getting an error on using sizeof operator, C++ does not allow to define a data structure inside sizeof operator , whereas C allows. So I am thinking to compile a function contains all sizeof operator using gcc.

Comment: @slugonamission, in C, `void*` acts as both `bottom*` and `top*` (type-thoretically), so malloc returns `void*`, but in C++, `void*` is only `top*`, whereas malloc needs to return `bottom*`, which doesn't actually exist, so not only does malloc have the wrong return type, it's not even possible to declare it with the correct return type.

Comment: @DavidX - aha, fair enough. Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile a specific function like this:
foo.cxx:

```
int bar(int); /* declare bar so c++ knows it exists */
int main(void)
    {
    return bar(41);
    }
```

bar.c:

```
int bar(int x)
    {
    return x+1;
    }
```

build:

```
$ gcc -c bar.c
$ g++ foo.c bar.o
```

Comment: Typically you would have a `bar.h` file here to define `bar()` rather than declaring it `extern`.

Comment: @RobNapier, that's true, but I wanted to keep the example short. Also, it looks like the extern token *is* redundant for functions, so I'm going drop that.

Answer (score 2):

You must move the function into a separate compile unit (a `.c` file), and link it. You cannot switch compilers in the middle of a compile unit.